# What is a good book for self-teaching, biomechanic and generally well rehabilitation?

Tags: gym, sports, physical-therapy, rehabilitation

Basically, I have lots of injuries and always get them, and would like to prevent them from happening again in the future, I believe they occur due to poor stretching or poor technique. I want to educate myself to prevent it from happening and do the exercises with the right technique. Is there any good book for self-teaching on biomechanics and just rehabilitation? Books that teach you to stretch probably and do's and don'ts. Good books on functional training?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you check out "Becoming a Supple Leopard" by Dr. Kelly Starrett. The book itself is a major investment, but you can check him out online, there are plenty of videos that will introduce you to his approach. His focus is on body mechanics and injury prevention and his book goes into great detail and is packed with photos. As a 57-year-old man who wants to stay strong and hates pain, I have found him invaluable.

Comment: I use "Supple Leopard" by Dr. Kelly Starrett and it is great. Also you could consider purchasing a yoga book with pictures.  I have a book called "2100 Asanas" by Daniel Lacerda and Mr. Yoga. contains a bunch of stretches that i find very helpful even if you don't practice yoga.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly having spent 10 years studying biomechanics, rehabilitation etc etc.. I commend you for taking the time to educate yourself.

- What types of injuries do you keep getting and what is causing them?  I may be able to offer some general advice.

***As far as books go***

---

- I highly recommend ***"Core Performance by Mark Verstegen"***  you can find
  it for $2 on amazon.
- Also have a look at the following page.  Under the heading "Popular Topics",  you'll find a ton of great dynamic warm up, prehab and region specific exercises.

  http://www.coreperformance.com/daily/movement/

---

- Anything by ***Gray Cook*** is another fantastic resource.  The man's a genius.

  http://graycook.com/
- He offers both basic and medically based movement screens that
  provide a quick way to identify imbalances.

  See his Functional Movement Screen (FMS)

  http://www.graycookmovement.com

---

Hope they help. If you need more or have any questions let me know.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, the world is improved by small good things done by people like you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend:

1. *The Barbell Prescription*, which explains from human physiology why to train for strength, and why to use barbells to do so.
2. *Starting Strength: Basic Barbell Training*, which explains from physics, anatomy, and biomechanics how to perform the basic barbell movements (that is, squat, press, deadlift, and bench press), and why to do them in the described ways, and what to do to correct common movement-pattern errors.

Please note that neither of these books devotes much attention to stretching.  Similarly, neither of them discusses "functional training" much; they advocate *strength training* as the most functional training, because strength is the most-significant and most-trainable factor in physical function.